# Revolute joint in Gazebo with gazebo_ros_control not working

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems like we can't control revolute joints with gazebo_ros_control plugin.

The easiest way to reproduce it is to clone the `gazebo_ros_demos` repo and edit the rrbot.xacro by replacing the continuous joint with a revolute joint.

Then the control doesn't work anymore.

here is the part of the urdf I changed (l.55-63 of `rrbot.xacro`):

```
  <joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1"/>
    <child link="link2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 ${width} ${height1 - axel_offset}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>

    <limit effort="100" velocity="30" upper="-3.14" lower="3.14"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
  </joint>
```

Has anybody succeeded in controlling revolute joints in gazebo ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24841/revolute-joint-in-gazebo-with-gazebo_ros_control-not-working/) by [ejalaa12](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7570/ejalaa12/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-04-16**:
Have you specified the limits?

**Comment by [ejalaa12](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7570/ejalaa12/) on 2020-04-16**:
@kumpakri yes I did, I just edited my question with the part I changed

**Comment by [ejalaa12](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7570/ejalaa12/) on 2020-04-16**:
I think I found my mistakes, I swapped the upper and lower limit values ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the solution, the lower and upper limit were inverted

---

Originally posted by [ejalaa12](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7570/ejalaa12/) with karma: 1 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0